# Some kind of iteration

Tags: haskell, iteration

Sorry if the title is bad...

So my problem is that i got this code:

```
asd (a:as) (b:bs)= tail(rox(tail(rox (tail (rox (a:as) (b:bs))) (b:bs))) (b:bs))
rox [] as = as
rox as [] = as
rox (a:as) (b:bs) = map abs (a-b:rox as bs)
```

my type must be: `asd :: [Int]->[Int]->[Int]`

I spent my half day figuring out a good solution, but I just cant think on one, so I would be very happy if someone could help me.
I want to subtract from the (a:as)list the (b:bs)list and after this I want to delete the first number and do it again with the result(result-(b:bs)), until I get a (length (b:bs))-1) list. And if the (a:as)/result is lower than the (b:bs), for exapmle: 00101<10011 I need to change all (b:bs) numbers to 0(and if the result is higher again keep using the (b:bs)). The exapmle is working fine with the code above, but I want to use it with any list. Maybe I need to use the iterate function but I wasnt able to figure out how.

Here is an example:

```
11010(a:as)
101(b:bs)
01110(result)
 1110(after using tail)
 101(b:bs again)
 0100(result)
  100(after tail)
  101(b:bs)
  001(result)
   01(final result after using tail, so its 1number shorter than the (b:bs) list
```

Thank you so much for your help!

edit: 
With this I can check which binary number is higher, so with this I can turn all bs number into 0, but i dont know how to implement it.

```
(%>=%) :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
(%>=%) [] [] = True
(%>=%) as [] = True
(%>=%) [] bs = False
(%>=%) as bs
    | filter (/=0) (takeWhile (>(-1))(ro as bs))==[]=False
    | elem 1 (takeWhile (>(-1))(ro as bs))==True=True

ro :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
ro []       bs       = bs
ro as       []       = as
ro (a:as) (b:bs) = (2*a) - b: ro as bs
```

Result:

```
asd [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0] [1,1,0,1,1]
asd [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0] [1,1,0,1,1]
asd [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0] [1,1,0,1,1]
asd [0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0] [1,1,0,1,1]
asd [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0] [1,1,0,1,1]
asd [0,1,1,0,0,0,0] [1,1,0,1,1] < here is something wrong because its: 1,1,0,1,0,0,0 and from here everything is wrong
asd [1,1,0,0,0,0] [1,1,0,1,1]
asd [1,0,0,0,0] [1,1,0,1,1]
asd [0,0,0,0] [1,1,0,1,1]
[0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Should it only work for `1` and `0`?

Comment: Are you trying to implement [the remainder function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:rem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to implement the remainder `rem` (similar to modulo `mod`) function but for binary lists. It is much faster if you convert the list to an `Integer` and perform `rem` on it.

First, a function that converts from binary to an `Integer`:

```
unbinary :: [Int] -> Integer
unbinary = foldl (\ a b -> a * 2 + fromIntegral b) 0
```

Then, a function that converts an `Integer` into binary:

```
binary :: Integer -> [Int]
binary = reverse . go
  where
    go 0 = []
    go d =
      let (q, r) = quotRem d 2
      in fromIntegral r : binary q
```

Finally, a function that handles `rem` for binary lists:

```
remBinary :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
remBinary a b = binary $ inta `rem` intb
  where
    inta = unbinary a
    intb = unbinary b
```

The "beauty" of this solution is that you can replace the 2's with any number (3, 6, 13 etc) and it will work for any base - not just binary.

---

To answer your original question:

This is a very strange function indeed, and I would **not** use `iterate` for it.

```
asd :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
-- If there is nothing to subtract, let's assume that we should return as
asd as [] = as
asd as bs
  -- If the length of `as` is shorter than `bs`, we are done.
  | length as < length bs
  = as
  | head as == 0
  = asd (tail as) bs
  -- Otherwise, compute `rox as bs`, take its `tail`, and call `asd` recursively
  | otherwise
  = asd (tail (rox as bs)) bs

-- I simplified your version of this function a bit
rox :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
rox []       bs       = bs
rox as       []       = as
rox (a : as) (b : bs) = abs (a - b) : rox as bs
```

The last part of `asd` could also be written like this:

```
  = let diff = rox as bs
        tailOfDiff = tail diff
    in asd tailOfDiff bs
```

That way, it follows your description more closely.

Comment: Thank you! Its really working with the example my only problem is when the result(not the final result) is lower than the bs 00101<10011, i need to change all bs number to 0 and if the result is higher keep using the normal bs. I hope you can understand me. :)

Comment: No, sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "change all `bs` number to 0". Should `bs` be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`? Then, `rox as bs` will be the same as just `as`. Maybe you should say what you want to do with this program (the goal) instead of adding constraints.

Comment: I want to do a program which works like `mod` but on binary numbers.

Comment: Do you have to use those functions, or is it OK if a much simpler solution is used?

Comment: It would be good to use these, but its ok to use a much simpler too. :)

Comment: I made the solution much simpler (see updated answer). If you don't want to use the built-in `rem` function, it is much easier to write it for `Integer`s than for lists, but I don't know what you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for your work, but I want to work with lists, its like a cheat to convert them into an Int, thats why i started to make the way as above :) I made a function to check which binary number is higher, but i dont know where to implement it, I edited my post

Comment: See the line `= asd (tail (if as < bs then as else rox as bs)) bs`; the `<` function should work, you shouldn't need your `%>=%` function. (I haven't had access to a computer this entire time, so I can't run code)

Comment: Hm yea, but something is wrong, because on the small first example I get [0,0] instead of [0,1]

Comment: Try doing `import Debug.Trace` and then before the current two versions of `asd`, add the line `asd as bs | trace ("asd " ++ show as ++ " " ++ show bs) False = undefined`. This will print the arguments to every iteration of `asd` and you can see what the error is.

Comment: Edited my post, it seems like at the end it dont get the [0,0,1] result and its just tail the [1,0,0]

Comment: No, I don't fully understand how you want your algorithm to work, so I cannot help you unless you offer a different approach.

Comment: I try to explain it better, but I cant be more specific than the example. Well as you can see in the example every time I use tail the (as) is always bigger than the (bs), but there is some case where the (as) gonna be lower than the (bs) (0010<0100) and if that is the case I want change all (bs) numbers to 0 on that call(for example after a call I get 0010 (as) and my original (bs) is 0100 so i want to change the (bs) to 0000 and subtract it from (as)), but if the next result (as) is higher then keep calling the function with the original (bs).

Comment: The code that I presented already does that. I understand what you *told me to do* before, so the code *does what you say*, but not what you *want the algorithm to do*.

Comment: Umm...Then what I want, if what I say is wrong? :) I copied in my post what was the result with the example and u can see too that something is wrong.

Comment: Edited my post with another result, i marked where the problem is.

Comment: Finally I made it :) The `if as < bs` was wrong I used my function (%>=%): `if (%>=%) as bs==False` and its working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, so what you **want** is this: if `as = [0, 0, 1]` and `bs = [1, 0]`, if `as` is shorter than `bs` then return `as`; else if `as` starts with a zero, remove that zero, else subtract `bs` from `as`. You don't need `%>=%`.